# Which delegate function is called within a class on tapping the home-button

Tags: ios, delegates, onresume, home-button

I have a pop-up which has to be hidden when the user moves away from the class. 
On tapping on the home button, the doesn't happen.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

Other than the above functions is there any other delegate functions which would be called in the same class (not the app-delegate class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the `UIApplicationDelegate` defines those methods. If you want any other class to handle those events, you need to have the class register for the corresponding notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(backgrounding) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
```

And don't forget to remove the observer.

Then you need the method:

```
- (void)backgrounding {
    // App entered background
}
```